# How can changes a DIV in Default.aspx from a web user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Default.aspx and a web user control that adds in Default.aspx

Is there any way that i can change value of a div in Default.aspx from web user control?

for example :

```
<meta name="description" content="" id="MetaDescription" runat="server"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="" id="MetaKeywords" runat="server"/>
```

or :

```
<div id="test" runat="server"></div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change value of parent page's any control, I made my sample for label control by using the following code. I have made one sample please check it.

**Main Page ASPX:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"  Inherits="UseUsercontrol.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="My" TagName="UserInfoBoxControl" Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <My:UserInfoBoxControl runat="server" ID="MyUserInfoBoxControl" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Main Page"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**User control ASCX:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="UseUsercontrol.WebUserControl1" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

**User Control CS:**

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label parentPanel = this.Parent.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
        parentPanel.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
```

Here i am updating parent page's Label control value with child's textbox latest value which enter by user.

Hope it will help you. if i am going wrong then please let me know i will try to update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a dive from codebehind but you cannot manipulate it's inner html.

If you want to ad a div and it's inner html from codebehid,

Create a user control and add a literal control

```
<asp:Literal Text="" ID="literal" runat="server" />
```

Add it to the aspx page

From the code behind of the aspx page,

```
Literal litereal = MyUserControl1.FindControl("literal") as Literal;
litereal.Text = string.Format("<div id=\"test\" runat=\"server\">{0}</div>", "any text or html");
```